# Mongo client cannot connect on first try in bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb

I'm working on a bash script for automatic MongoDB server installation and user creation.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mongodb-org
update-rc.d mongod defaults
sed -i 's/^auth = true/#auth = true/g' /etc/mongod.conf
sed -i 's/^#noauth = true/noauth = true/g' /etc/mongod.conf
service mongod restart
mongo user_creation.js
```

The script is run on a clean precise64 Vagrant VM. Add the Debian/Ubuntu repo to install the latest version (we're on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the maintained version is 2.0.X), add server to startup, set some variables in the MongoDB config file. Simple stuff really, however, *the last line fails each and every time*.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4 connecting to: test 2014-10-03T12:34.:56.000+0000 
warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-10-03T12:34.:56.000+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 
(127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I thought maybe the server needed some time to load data or some other kind of initialization between its restart and the client connection so I tried putting a `sleep 30` between the last two instructions : didn't work. However, removing the `mongo` execution from the script and starting it manually works like a charm every time! The .js is not the problem here, I've tested it and it's working alright.

Does anyone have any idea why the `mongo` cannot connect on its first try and how I could fix this? For now, I'll settle with this terrible (working) hack, but I'd rather have a cleaner, hackless script:

```
while :
do
    RESULT=`mongo --eval "1;"`
    echo $RESULT

    if [[ "${RESULT:-null}" == *Failed\ to\ connect* ]]
    then
        sleep 1
    else
        mongo root_creation.js
        break;
    fi
done
```

It's ugly but after 1 to 10 tries, it ends up connecting and working perfectly.

Comment: Better to ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com. Please post your mongod.conf there too.